# monitoring a child process from the parent process

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, libc, fuzzing

I'm trying to fuzz using **AFL** (***Qemu-mode***) a binary-app that keeps waiting for data, and because I don't have the source code to modify the binary so that it `exit(0)` after parsing the data, I'm faced with a problem in AFL (`timeout`), so I decided to write a wrapper around the binary so that I can make it exit after a certain time passes, with that in mind.

1. AFL fuzzer: it can passes test inputs through
   `STDIN` or as an `argument file`
2. the binary-app that I'm fuzzing expects the input to be in the `STDIN` and just keep waiting for input

---

My strategies are based on **parent/child style (forking)** such that the child will be the binary-app and the parent will monitor it.

- the parent makes the child(binary-app) exit with a 0 status if
  nothing happens for 5 seconds (no crash happens in the child process).
- and also the parent is responsible for sending the input to the child that it receives from `stdin`
- if the child crash I want the parent to crash as well so that `AFL`
  will notice that and save the test file that is responsible for the
  crash

my questions are :

- how can you make a **child exit with a status of 0** from the **parent**?
- how to **send the data** to the **child** process **from the parent** process
  **after the child runs the binary-app using** `exec()`?
- is it a good idea to tell if the **child crashed based** on the **exit
  status of the child**?

Comment: "how can you make a child exit with a status of 0 from the parent". You can only do it if the child is coded to exit 0 under some condition and you can trigger one of those conditions.

Comment: "how to send the data to the child process from the parent process". This one is doable. And is covered in many posts on Stackoverflow and the web in general. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405985/linux-3-0-executing-child-process-with-piped-stdin-stdout

Comment: @kaylum I'm not the original coder of the binary-app so I have no idea about what condition triggers the exit(0) and the binary is static linked with no symbols so reversing  is hard even with signatures based tools like IDA PRO (didn't recognize anything )

Comment: Well then you can't do what you want. That was my point.

Comment: But I don't really see that you need to do that. Just have the parent kill the child and exit with 0 if the child hasn't crashed. If it has crashed then exit with the child's non-zero exit status which can be obtained via `wait`.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly the answer to the question you are asking, but ...

> because I don't have the source code to modify the binary so that it exit(0) after parsing the data,

The premise above is *false*.

> I decided to write a wrapper around the binary so that I can make it exit after a certain time passes,

That approach, while workable, will waste a lot of time: you don't know how long the parsing takes, so you'll have to wait some maximum time. If you don't wait long enough, you miss test coverage. And you also miss coverage of the parser  going into infinite loop.

---

So how *can* you make the program `exit(0)` after parsing? By binary patching. Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26194442/50617).

You'll need to find a place in the binary where the `ParseInput()` (or whatever it's called) routine returns, and patch a few instructions to execute the equivalent of `syscall(SYS_exit, 0)`.

Afer that, your fuzzing will go much faster (no wasting time waiting when parsing is already done) and you'll be able to detect when the parser goes into infinite loop.