# How to ignore execution of some line of binary file?

Tags: c++, assembly, gdb, cracking

I want to make my program more strong in front of hackers, so i have a `program::validator` class which validate my environment by some parameters. I :

- Compile `program::validator` shared library.
- Compile program using `-O2` and `--ffast-math` and link to `libprogramvalidator.so`.
- Run the program with the GDB.
- Find the line which actually call `program::validator::is_valid_system()`.

and i want know that i can ignore execution of those line ?

Comment: Do you want to run gdb and ignore the line during normal execution or once for testing?

Comment: Yes, you can skip instructions and change registers using a debugger. You can also patch the binary itself to do this.

Comment: When you say "ignore execution of those line", do you want to avoid  the execution of the entire line that calls is_valid_system, including any other side effects made by any expression in that line, or do you want to just avoid the execution of is_valid_system?

Comment: The question as stated is exceedingly unclear. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @Sebastian, Yes.

Comment: @Jester, So how i can do it ? please give me a document.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, I just want to avoid execution of `is_valid_system`.

Comment: @EmployedRussian, Sorry i thought it was clear, i just want avoid call to `is_valid_system` function in my ELF executable binary file.

Comment: If it is so easy to circumvent your hurdles against hackers, you should consider making them stronger ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> i just want avoid call to is_valid_system function in my ELF executable binary file.

There are several easy ways. You can use GDB `jump $address`, or `return` commands to achieve this. Example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int is_valid_system()
{
  return 0;
}

int main()
{
  if (is_valid_system()) {
    printf("Life is good\n");
    return 0;
  }
  printf("Invalid system detected\n");
  return 1;
}
```

As you can see, running above program will always print `Invalid system` and exit with error code 1. Let's confirm that:

```
gcc t.c && gdb -q ./a.out
(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/a.out 
Invalid system detected
[Inferior 1 (process 180727) exited with code 01]
```

Ok, now let's make the program print `Life is good`. Let's do that via `return`. To achieve that, set a breakpoint on the desired function, set return register (`$rax` on `x86_64`) to desired value, and `return` to force the function to immediately return:

```
(gdb) b is_valid_system
Breakpoint 1 at 0x1139
(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/a.out 

Breakpoint 1, 0x0000555555555139 in is_valid_system ()
(gdb) set $rax = 1
(gdb) return
#0  0x000055555555514e in main ()
(gdb) c
Continuing.
Life is good
[Inferior 1 (process 196141) exited normally]
```

Alternatively, you can "jump over" the function. Disasemble the caller, break on the `CALL` instruction, set return register to desired value, and jump to next instruction:

```
(gdb) disas main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0000555555555140 <+0>:     push   %rbp
   0x0000555555555141 <+1>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000555555555144 <+4>:     mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x0000555555555149 <+9>:     callq  0x555555555135 <is_valid_system>
   0x000055555555514e <+14>:    test   %eax,%eax
   0x0000555555555150 <+16>:    je     0x555555555165 <main+37>
   0x0000555555555152 <+18>:    lea    0xeab(%rip),%rdi        # 0x555555556004
   0x0000555555555159 <+25>:    callq  0x555555555030 <puts@plt>
   0x000055555555515e <+30>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x0000555555555163 <+35>:    jmp    0x555555555176 <main+54>
   0x0000555555555165 <+37>:    lea    0xea5(%rip),%rdi        # 0x555555556011
   0x000055555555516c <+44>:    callq  0x555555555030 <puts@plt>
   0x0000555555555171 <+49>:    mov    $0x1,%eax
   0x0000555555555176 <+54>:    pop    %rbp
   0x0000555555555177 <+55>:    retq   
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) b *0x0000555555555149
Breakpoint 2 at 0x555555555149
(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/a.out 

Breakpoint 2, 0x0000555555555149 in main ()
(gdb) set $rax = 1
(gdb) jump *0x000055555555514e
Continuing at 0x55555555514e.
Life is good
[Inferior 1 (process 205378) exited normally]
```

You could also use GDB to temporarily or permanently patch the `is_valid_system` out. Details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26194442/50617).

Comment: Wow, that is great. But i did it in another way. First i take a dump of binary file with `objdump` and find the line which check system validation and use `dd` to write `\x90` at that section and system validation was gone.

Comment: @Kate The _other_ answer I linked to shows  how to patch the binary using GDB, which is a bit easier than using `dd`.

Answer (score 3):

This is another variant of the common mistake "Thinking that you can trust your environment, even when you cannot trust your environment".

You implicitly trust that the compiler is a real compiler, the linker a real linker, GDB the real GDB, and the disassembler a real disassembler. You have given hackers not one but four ways to attack your program.

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand what you mean.